# Calling API from PigLatin

Tags: apache-pig

Complete newbie to PigLatin, but looking to pull data from the MetOffice DataPoint API e.g.:

http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/xml/350509?res=3hourly&key=abc123....

...into Hadoop.

My question is "Can this be undertaken using PigLatin (from within Pig View, in Ambari)"?

I've hunted round for how to format a GET request into the code, but without luck.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? Should I be looking to use a different service within the Hadoop framework to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very bad idea to make calls to external services from inside of map-reduce jobs.  The reason being that when running on the cluster your jobs are very scalable whereas the external system might not be so.  Modern resource managers like YARN make this situation even worse,  when you swamp external system with the requests your tasks on the cluster will be mostly sleeping waiting for reply from the server.  The resource manager will see that CPU is not being used by tasks and will schedule more of your tasks to run which will make even more requests to the external system, swamping it with the requests even more.   I've seen modest 100 machine cluster putting out 100K requests per second.

What you really want to do is to either somehow get the bulk data from the web service or setup a system with a queue and few controlled number of workers that will pull from the external system at set rate.

As for your original question,  I don't think PigLatin provides such service, but it could be easily done with UDFs either Python or Java.  With Python you can use excellent [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library,  which will make your UDF be about 6 lines of code.  Java UDF will be little bit more verbose,  but nothing terrible by Java standards.

Comment: Many thanks @Vlad, I'll explore the Python requests library as you suggest.

Comment: I agree this is usually a bad idea, but what if I actually want to hit the rest api from a job to saturate the destination as part of an ETL?  Can it be done, and can it be throttled?

Answer (score 0):

> "Can this be undertaken using PigLatin (from within Pig View, in
>   Ambari)"?

No, by default Pig load from HDFS storage, unless you write your own loader.

And i share same point with @Vlad, that this is not a good idea, you have many other other components used for data ingestion, but this not a use case of Pig !

Comment: Thanks for your help @54l3d